# Angularjs form validation errors not showing when novalidate is given in form

Tags: angularjs

on submit of form tag i want to display the custom error messages,

my form is

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="new-session-form" name="saveSessionForm" ng-model="saveSessionForm" ng-submit="saveSession()" novalidate>

<textarea class="form-control" name="sessionTopic" ng-model="session.topic" required></textarea>

<div ng-show="submitted && saveSessionForm.sessionTopic.$error.required" class="error">Session Name cannot be blank.</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm ng-click="submitted=true">Save</button>
```

am able to see the custom validation error message when i remove the novalidate from the form tag...

but if the write the novalidate in the form tag then on click of button i am not able to see the custom validation error message..

what i am doing wrong... please help...

Comment: Could you prepare a fiddle demonstrating the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT based on your updated requirement:**

Have separate validations for your elements in the HTML:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="sessionTopic" ng-model="session.topic" required></textarea>
<div ng-show="saveSessionForm.sessionTopic.$error.required" class="error">Session topic cannot be blank.</div>
```

In the controller, validate the whole form with `$valid`:

```
 $scope.saveSession = function(){
        if($scope.saveSessionForm.$valid){
            alert("Saving");       
        }
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/8n9Td/2/)**

2 ways to achieve this:

First, if you want to validate upon submitting:

```
<div ng-show="errorExists" class="error">Session Name cannot be blank.</div>

$scope.saveSession = function(){
    if ($scope.saveSessionForm.$valid) {
       $scope.errorExists = false;
        alert("Saving");
    } else {
       $scope.errorExists = true;
    }                
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/8n9Td/)

Second, upon typing and deleting:

```
<div ng-show="saveSessionForm.$valid" class="error">Session Name cannot be blank.</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/8n9Td/1/)**

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

`novalidate` basically means that the form is not to be validated on submit:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp

So you are technically telling it to validate [with `required`] then negating that with `novalidate`. That's why it won't work unless you remove `novalidate`.

In other words, `novalidate` is overriding `required`. You may want to use that if you want to come up with your own JavaScript validation rules.

Comment: What you say applies to "normal" HTML5. This is an AngularJS app and things are a little different :)

Comment: thanks for your reply... but when i use submitted && saveSessionForm.sessionTopic.$error.required, why it is not showing the message, because it should work right... like this i have 3 more other fields, then for every field i have write false in valid and true in else block....